# JBOSS XML files understanding

Tags: xml, syntax, jboss

I used to be indifferent about the content of JBoss files. But now, I really would like to understand what would things mean ( double dots separator, urn, ... ).

Here it is the snippet I would like to receive an explaination for :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.2" default-stack="${jboss.default.jgroups.stack:udp}">
  ...
</subsystem>
```

Well, true this was taken from an Infinispan Server, but I would like to understand that tree `"urn:jboss:....."`. It is more about syntax interpretation way than what infinispan is trying to do.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it is that when JBoss7 was released didn't they change to using JGroups for clustering?  JBoss6 and earlier used netcast mod_jk or the newer AJP13 protocols instead right?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.0" default-stack="udp">
<stack name="udp">
<transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"
diagnostics-socket-binding="jgroups-diagnostics"/>
<protocol type="PING"/>
<protocol type="MERGE2"/>
<protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
<protocol type="FD"/>
<protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
<protocol type="BARRIER"/>
<protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
<protocol type="UNICAST"/>
<protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
<protocol type="VIEW_SYNC"/>
<protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
<protocol type="UFC"/>
<protocol type="MFC"/>
<protocol type="FRAG2"/>
<protocol type="pbcast.STREAMING_STATE_TRANSFER"/>
<protocol type="pbcast.FLUSH"/>
</stack>
<!-- More stacks -->
</subsystem>
```

Bindings:

```
<socket-binding-group name="clustering-sockets" default-interface="loopback"
port-offset="0">
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200"
multicast-address="230.0.0.4" multicast-port="45688"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-diagnostics" port="0"
multicast-address="224.0.75.75" multicast-port="7500"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0"
multicast-address="230.0.0.4" multicast-port="45700"/>
</socket-binding-group>
```